# Draggable containment buggs when the draggable element is rotated

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a draggable element, which is also resizable and rotatable. These rotations are handled by CSS transformations, however, when an element is rotated, it makes the draggable feature spin out of control.

Heres a (updated) fiddle: [Click me](http://jsfiddle.net/wf71ddey/2/)

What I think happens is that when an element is rotated, it's height and width obviously stay the same, just at an angle, however, jQuery doesn't account for the rotation, making it think that the element is in it's normal horizontal way, which results in the "bugg" shown in the fiddle above.

In a wild goose chase for the answer, I read somewhere that this would do the trick:

```
refreshPositions: true,
```

But it didn't work. Neither did destroying the `draggable` function on the element and then reinitiating it. Is there a way to fix this, so the containment will function normally, thus making jQuery recognise the rotation?

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect you need to wrap the transformed element in a div. Make that div the draggable, and set the handle to the transformed element. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/fup2ga8p/ you can see the original box is still what the browser is using for it's bounding points.

Comment: Please, update your fiddle with `pixelsToPercentages` function in order to make it work

Comment: @DmytroGrynets Updated the fiddle :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to handle the containment yourself.  Here is one possible way to do that.

I am using getBoundingClientRect to get the height and width of the rotated element.  Using these values I can get an idea of where the dragged element resides in relation to it's parent container and force it to stay within those bounds.

```
var boundingContainer, boundingDraggable, prevLeft, prevTop;

$(".draggable").draggable({
  classes: {
    "ui-draggable-dragging": "highlight-draggable"
  },
  start: function(event, ui) {
    boundingDraggable = ui.helper[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    boundingContainer = ui.helper.closest('#draggableContainer')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  },
  drag: function(event, ui) {

    if(ui.offset.left <= boundingContainer.left){
      if(ui.position.left < prevLeft){
            ui.position.left = prevLeft;
      }
    }

    if(ui.offset.top <= boundingContainer.top){
      if(ui.position.top < prevTop){
            ui.position.top = prevTop;
      }
    }

    if(ui.offset.left+boundingDraggable.width >= boundingContainer.right){
        if(ui.position.left > prevLeft){
            ui.position.left = prevLeft;
      } 
    }

    if(ui.offset.top+boundingDraggable.height >= boundingContainer.bottom){
        if(ui.position.top > prevTop){
            ui.position.top = prevTop;
      } 
    }

    prevLeft = ui.position.left;
    prevTop = ui.position.top;
  }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/920bhk6t/)